Uploading Large WAV Sound Files into Github
I'm trying to upload large WAV files into a Github Repository that I have. They have music that will play in a game I'm designing. But Github won't let me upload them to the repository because they are more than 25 MB in size. What can I do to upload these large files without them losing their quality?
I've tried compressing them but the size is still too big.

Why do you need to have them in the repository? Can't you store them somewhere else?

I got music files to add to a BlackJack game that I’m making. I want to use these files for background music.
